# VBA - Loop Each Item in Pivot Filter and Paste into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a challenge... I have a range in Sheet Lookup with each possible value in Pivot table filter "Owner: Full Name".

The range with the names are Sheets "Lookup" Range B2:B98. (Problem 1: This range can change as it creates this list in a different code, how to set this to a dynamic range?)

Once it filters on that i.e. value in B2 it should copy this filtered pivot into a new sheet and name the sheet after the value in b2.

Then it should "deselect" the b2 item and go to filter on value in b3 and continue.

Problem 2: Setting the filter correctly to loop and filter on each single value in the new dynamic lookup range.

Here is what I have at the moment...

```
Option Explicit

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet, PT As PivotTable, PTI As 
    PivotItem, PTF As PivotField, rng As Range

    Sub Filter_Pivot()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Copy")
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Lookup")
    Set PT = ws.PivotTables("PivotCopy")
    Set PTF = PT.PivotFields("Owner: Full Name")


        For Each rng In ws1.Range("B2:B98")
            With PTF
                .ClearAllFilters
                For Each PTI In PTF.PivotItems
                    PTI.Visible = (PTI.Name = rng)
                Next PTI
            Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
                ws1.Name = PTI
                .TableRange2.Copy
                ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            End With
        Next rng


    End Sub
```

Comment: To make your lookup range dynamic, consider using the [`End`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-end-property-excel) property. Also don't you mean `ws2.Name`, not `ws1`? Finally, what errors are you having currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to avoid all this and use the `PivotTable.ShowPages Method`. It is optimized for this sort of operation.

---

**Note:**

1. `"Owner: Full Name"` ***must*** be in the page field area at the top.
2. You probably want to check the sheet names don't already exist. You could do an initial loop of sheet names that will be generated from pivot and try deleting them (wrapping inside an `On Error Resume Next, attempt delete, On Error GoTo 0`) to ensure they don't exist first. I have shown how to do this in the second example.

---

**Info:** [PivotTable.ShowPages Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-showpages-method-excel)

> Creates a new PivotTable report for each item in the page field. Each
>   new report is created on a new worksheet.
>
> Syntax expression . ShowPages( PageField )
>
> expression A variable that represents a PivotTable object.
>
> [Optional parameter of pageField.]

---

**Code:**

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy").PivotTables("PivotCopy").ShowPages "Owner: Full Name"
```

---

This will produce a sheet for each possible value in the page field `"Owner: Full Name"`. If you don't want all of them, simply hold a list of sheet names for sheets to keep, in an array, and loop over all sheets in workbook and if not in array then delete as shown below:

### ① Example of looping sheets and deleting if not in array:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GeneratePivots()
    Dim keepSheets(), ws As Worksheet
    keepSheets = Array("FilterValue1", "FilterValue2","Lookup","Copy") '<== List of sheet names to keep

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    On Error GoTo errHand

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy").PivotTables("PivotCopy").ShowPages "Owner: Full Name"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, keepSheets, 0)) And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws

errHand:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

### ② Using a lookup sheet:

If you do want to still read in the sheets to keep from the `Copy` sheet then you can use the following (**but** be sure to include in the list in column B the sheet names `Copy`,`Lookup`, the filter values of interest, and any other sheet names you don't want deleted):

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GeneratePivots()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lookups As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookup")
        Set lookups = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(lookups) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        keepSheets = lookups.Value
    End With

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In lookups
        On Error Resume Next
         Select Case rng.Value
         Case "Lookup", "Copy" '<=Extend for sheets to keep listed in lookups that aren't generated by the pivot filtering
         Case Else
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rng.Value).Delete
         End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next rng

   On Error GoTo errHand

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy").PivotTables("PivotCopy").ShowPages "Owner: Full Name"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(keepSheets, 0, 1), 0)) And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws

errHand:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

### Example run:

[image: Test run]

Comment: Hello, I think this works well. However, it jumps to error for me directly as "Owner: Full Name" isn't a pivot page. So it doesn't find the item in it. Any ideas on how I can work with it if the field isn't a page?

Comment: It won’t work unless in page field. Is it not possible to use in page field?

Comment: The alternative is to loop through that field where ever it is placed, selecting items.

Comment: Bear in mind you could create a duplicate pivot in a different sheet which it in the page field and use that to generate the sheets if you want to preserve the original with its existing layout. Making sure to point the code at the duplicate pivot.

Comment: I got it working great now. Thanks a lot for that. Just tweeked it a little and now it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub Filter_Pivot()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTF As PivotField
Dim rng As Range
Dim lr As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Copy")
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Lookup")
Set PT = ws.PivotTables("PivotCopy")
Set PTF = PT.PivotFields("Owner: Full Name")

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In ws1.Range("B2:B" & lr)
    PTF.ClearAllFilters
    On Error Resume Next
    PTF.CurrentPage = rng.Value
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set ws2 = Sheets(rng.Value)
        ws2.Cells.Clear
        If ws2 Is Nothing Then
            Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
            ws2.Name = rng.Value
        End If
        PT.TableRange2.Copy ws2.Range("A1")
    End If
    PTF.ClearAllFilters
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for this. However, it doesn't seem to work fully. Running through it it seems that it gets stuck on "If Err = 0 Then" and it keeps skipping the create new sheet and paste in... any ideas?

Comment: If an item is not found in the pivot field, `PTF.CurrentPage = rng.Value` will throw an error. And If there is no error that means item was found and a new sheet will be added and pivot table range would be copied in there. Just add another line `On Error GoTo 0` just after the line `Set ws2 = Nothing`, that will reset the error handler.

Comment: Tried that. Still not working, appears there is an error when it tries to find the value in the range (although it find the range with 98 lines and they are identical to pivot value). Thoughts?

Comment: What is not working? Is it not creating new sheets for some items? If yes, make sure that those items are exactly same as items in the column B on ws1. Check for leading or trailing spaces. Otherwise I don't see any issue in the code.

Comment: Or try to debug the code with `F8` key and see where the code skips creating a new sheet and then check `rng.Value` and compare it with the item in page field and see if they are exactly same.

Comment: Just wondering, could it have to do with "Err" not being defined?

Comment: It skips after If Err = 0 Then and goes to End If.... rng.value has a name from the lookup list. But seems to skip as mentioned.

Comment: So it doesn't create any sheets at all

Comment: I asked you to place the line `On Error GoTo 0`. Did you place it? Though I have edited the code now. Is it possible for you to share the file? If so, upload it on either Google drive or DropBox and share the link here.